# windows narrator reading labels/button more than one time in wpf but tab working as expcted(reading 1 time)

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, accessibility

In my WPF application we have buttons and labels. with windows narrator**(ctrl+win+enter)**it should be read only once for up and down arrow keys, narrator is not reading as expected. reading more than 2 times(exactly 5 times) where as with TAB  key , it is reading one time as expceted.

the above scenario is happening when scan mode is on **(CAPSLOCK + TAB)**

can someone suggest me the scenario to read it only once with ARROWS Keys.

Thank you!

The expectation is read one time with arrow keys in scan mode

Comment: I guess even for a WPF specialist this will be hard to answer without any shared code.

Comment: What happens with JAWS or NVDA?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.